# Creación de interfase para componentes de React

Tags: reactjs

Actualmente estoy trabajndo con react y estoy usando un diseño atomico,
estoy intentando crear componentes completamente independientes y todo funciona muy bien.
mi pregunta es si hay forma que a un componente se le puedad definir los datos que le deben llegar por pros, una especie de interfase o algo asi?, la idea es que restrinja mediante código

Comment: Ya revisaste PropTypes?

Comment: No, pero ahora mismo me pondre en eso

Comment: Parece ser lo que busco, muchas gracias

Comment: Con mucho gusto ;)